# Android Studio + Linux: How to retrieve key-alias

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

I forgot my key-alias but still remember my key-password.

I am working on Linux Ubuntu 14.04 and using Android studio.

Comment: Previously-answered question does not address Android Studio aspect of this one.

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio, you can find the path to your keystore when you choose *Generate Signed APK* from the *Build* menu. Once you know where your keystore is, use `keytool` from that location to show information about its contents. Of course you need to know the keystore password. For example, from the directory containing the keystore file:

```
$ keytool -list -v -keystore my-keystore
Enter keystore password:

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

Alias name: my-release-key
Creation date: Jan 20, 2015
...
```

The alias for each key, if present, is shown on the corresponding `Alias name` line.